# Allow to save a chat conversation

Tags: feature-request, chat

It would be nice to be able to export a chat conversation in some format (e.g. plain text).

Comment: Can you explain *why* this "would be nice"? I.e. what would you use this feature for?

Comment: So that I can look at the conversation later? The conversation may contain code snippets or just tips that I may find useful later.